Ecllipse store update store not working with records and micronaut
Root object
public class Root {
    private Map<UUID, Country> country = new HashMap<>();

    @NonNull
    public Map<UUID, Country> getCountry() {
        return this.country;
    }
}

Country Entity
public record Country(UUID id,
                      String name,
                      String shortName,
                      String url,
                      Optional<Integer> matchPlayed,
                      Optional<Integer> win,
                      Optional<Integer> draw,
                      Optional<Integer> lost,
                      Optional<Integer> points) {
}

Repository
@Singleton
public non-sealed class CountryRepository implements ICountryRepository {
private final RootProvider<Root> rootProvider;
public CountryRepository(RootProvider<Root> rootProvider,
                         CountryToResponseMapper countryToResponseMapper,
                         RequestToCountryMapper requestToCountryMapper) {
    this.rootProvider = rootProvider;
    this.countryToResponseMapper = countryToResponseMapper;
    this.requestToCountryMapper = requestToCountryMapper;
}

@Override
public Optional<CountryResponse> patch(UUID id, CountryRequest request) {
    Country country = rootProvider.root().getCountry().get(id);
    if (country == null)
        throw new RuntimeException(Constants.NO_Record_Found);
    var updateCountry = updateCountry(country,request);
    return Optional.of(this.countryToResponseMapper.apply(updateCountry));
}


@StoreReturn
protected Country updateCountry(Country country, CountryRequest request) {
    return this.requestToCountryMapper.apply(request, country);
}
}

RequestToCountryMapper
@Singleton
public record RequestToCountryMapper() implements BiFunction<CountryRequest,Country, Country> {
    @Override
    public Country apply(CountryRequest countryRequest, Country country) {
        return new Country(country.id(),
                countryRequest.name(),
                countryRequest.shortName(),
                countryRequest.url(),
                countryRequest.matchPlayed(),
                countryRequest.win(),
                countryRequest.draw(),
                countryRequest.lost(),
                countryRequest.points());
    }
}

The updated value Belgium is changed to Belgiumm

When I do a get request again, the old value is trigger. The update didn't happen

With map if we put the same id it will update the value. So the implementation  will be
@Override
public Optional<CourseResponse> create(CourseRequest request) throws CourseDuplicateException {
    if (courseData.values().stream().anyMatch(x -> x.name().equals(request.name())))
        throw new CourseDuplicateException(request.name());
    var course = requestToCourseMapper.apply(request);
    this.save(course);
    return Optional.of(courseToResponseMapper.apply(course));
}

@Override
public Optional<CourseResponse> update(UUID id, CourseRequest request) {
    Course course = courseData.get(id);
    if (course == null)
        throw new RuntimeException(Constants.NO_Record_Found);
    var updateCourse =  new Course(course.id(), request.name(), request.description());
    save(updateCourse);
    return Optional.of(this.courseToResponseMapper.apply(updateCourse));
}

@Override
public void delete(UUID id) {
    deleteCourseById(id);
}

@StoreParams("Course")
protected void save(@NonNull Course course) {
    courseData.put(course.id(), course);
}

@StoreParams("Course")
protected void deleteCourseById(@NonNull UUID id) {
    if (courseData.get(id) == null)
        throw new RuntimeException(Constants.NO_Record_Found);
    courseData.remove(id);
}

